# FIN omitted, FIN-ACK sent

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, tcp

As it's written on Wikipedia closing TCP connection should be using packets FIN->(FIN,ACK)->ACK. However when I use close() function to close socket I don't see FIN packet, there is instantly sent (FIN,ACK) packet from server to client, then client closes also connection by sending (FIN,ACK) and server responds with ACK packet. So where is the missing FIN packet (maybe it's merged to FIN,ACK)?

Comment: Are you sure, that the server didn't close the connection before? It looks like the server closes the connection

Comment: I don't see such a transition: http://blog.zhuzhaoyuan.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/tcp-states1.png
create a minimal tcpdump example.

Comment: I see that client sends FIN,ACK when I close socket with close() function then server responds with ACK

Comment: @scdmb Did you received only `ACK` from server or a `FIN, ACK` ?

Comment: It was FIN/ACK packet, looked more carefully

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The closing sequence can also be different and don't need to have FIN+ACK inside the same packet:

- ACK just acknowledges the receipt of data (e.g. received everything up to given sequence number)
- packets will be re-send until one receives an ACK for them
- FIN just says that the side sending the FIN will not send any more data. It gives no information if it will still receive data.
- like every other packet FIN will be re-send until the receipt is acknowledged

Protocols like HTTP support a one-sided shutdown, e.g. the client sends the request data followed by a FIN to notify the server, that it will not send anymore data. But it will still receive the data send by the server. The server will acknowledge the FIN like it did with all the data before. Once the server is done it will send its own FIN which the client ACKs. In this case you have

```
1. client: FIN  (will not send more) 
2. server: ACK (received the FIN)
.. server: sends more data..., client ACKs these data 
3. server: FIN (will not send more)
4. client: ACK (received the FIN)
```

Note that the packet you see in step#1 might have an ACK inside too. But this ACK just acknowledges data send before by the server. If the server has no more data to send it might close the connection also. In this case steps 2+3 can be merged, e.g. the server sends a FIN+ACK, where the ACK acknowledges the FIN received by the client.

If one side sends its FIN the connection is called half-closed. It is fully closed once both sides send their FIN and received the ACK for the FIN, no matter if they do this in 3 or 4 packets.

Comment: +1 The key to understanding the `ACK` is that it applies **to the specified acknowledgement number**. `FIN`+`ACK` isn't special **unless** the acknowledgement number is _lastdatabyte+1_ (because `FIN` counts in sequence numbers, just like `SYN` does).

Comment: Not really. This talks about optimizations like delayed ACK. The key is RFC793 (e.g. the RFC for TCP) section 3.5. But the RFC is not an easy read :)

Comment: `If the server has no more data to send it might close the connection also. In this case steps 2+3 can be merged`

Is there any document that mentions this one?

Comment: @kkkkgyg: Nowhere in TCP it is required that any state updates have to be delivered in separate packets. That's why you will find FIN+ACK in the same packet at end of connections and SYN+ACK in the same packet at start of connections.

Answer (score -2):

You must have already received the FIN for you to be sending a FIN/ACK. Are you closing in response to reading EOS?

Comment: I thought this too, because it's in the docs. But you can try with telnet and wireshark. The client really sends `FIN,ACK` .. Then the server sends `FIN,ACK` and finally the client the `ACK`.. Observed on Linux 3.2

Comment: It seems like it is somewhat optional because the server only checks if `FIN` is set. However, I guess there is still a meaning :)

Comment: No, it isn't 'somewhat optional', it is required by RFC 793. Can you answer my question?

Comment: I'm not the opener, unfortunately not. :)

Comment: That's not an answer to my question.

Comment: Which question? I digged trough Linux sources and at least there are 20 lines describing that, and why Linux differs from TCP standards while sending `FIN` .. Check net/tcp.c +1939 I'm currently investigating to understand whats the meaning of that behaviour

Comment: Btw, I'm not the opener of this question. Maybe you misunderstood this

Comment: I'm referring to the question in my answer. The part that ends with a question mark. The term you are looking  for is 'OP' or 'original poster'.

Comment: @EJP RFC 793 does not require the first FIN to not have the ACK flag set, there's even a scenario on page 38 that shows that.

Comment: @nos But this answers not his question! ;). I guess [RFC1122 section 4.2.3.2](http://tools.ietf.org/search/rfc1122#section-4.2.3.2) is the key. Am I wrong?